Facing runtime issue on STM32L452
I was working on a project with STM32L452RET6 using baremetal programming. I use Uart1, Uart2, I2C, Timer6, Timer2, RTC and GPIOs for my project. Uart2, RTC and Timer 6 works in interrupt with priority 1,0,2 respectively. Uart1 is remapped with printf statement for debugging purpose. Randomly facing "assertion "Balloc succeeded" failed: file "/build/gnu-tools-for-stm32_10.3-2021.10.20211105-1100/src/newlib/newlib/libc/stdlib/mprec.c", line 778" in the runtime and code gets stuck. Not able to identify the issue.

So what's mprec.c doing and what's on line 778?

not able to find that file in the repository. Its not a user defined file.

But isn't it open source and so you have access to the source? Even if a pre-built lib is linked directly to the project, you usually got access to the source regardless.

Anyway, took me around 1 minute to google down the most possible cause: a bug in newlib nano: https://forum.pjrc.com/index.php?threads/strange-compiling-problem-assertion-balloc-succeeded-failed-file-data-jenkins-w.72798/

It's a memory allocation issue. Have you identified if it's your code or the library that handles memory allocation failures poorly?
